# How to effectively prints lots of data using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am debugging a webpage using a bunch of `console.log` and `console.dir` calls but at some point, it just prints out too many things to the point where the browser freezes. Sometimes I might be printing extremely large amounts of data out, such as iterating over hundred thousand element array and printing out all the values.

Maybe the approach is wrong, but I would like all the data.
How can I log all this data? Preferably I would like to print this data onto disk in the end (either by copy pasting it from the console, or having the browser automatically create files for me).

Comment: Maybe using chromes build-in javascript debugger would be more suitable to find the bugs you are trying to find? You can reach it by pressing F12.

Comment: General question, general answer :-) Let me know if you want more elaboration.

Comment: @Philipp I'm using it for both logging and also debugging purposes. The call stack and scope variables are really nice, but there are dozens of variables and I have an idea which pieces of info that I need, so I figured just printing out what I want is faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use: http://www.json.org/

JSON is basically an object, but you can collect **MUCH** more data and display it easily without a stack overflow.

Using over 5000 `console.logs` will **eat the browser alive.** Use some sort of database structure, this being the easiest and most compatible with Javascript.

Comment: Hmm, so if I build a JSON that's say, 100 MB, and then print that out the console, will that also destroy my browser? I would like to export all that data at some point for analysis.

Comment: `JSON` is an object, so instead of creating `13589283 objects` *(console.log)*, you make one and `Javascript` can handle it much easier.

Comment: Oh, so it's creating a million objects that's causing the problem, and not so much the amount of data that I'm trying to display?

Comment: Correct. The `ironic part` is you are creating a `stack overflow`. Look at your `url`.

Comment: btw, if you can create a `JSON` file with `100mb` of **relevant** data, I would pay you at least 3 figures ;-)